# Java.Lang.RuntimeException : Font asset not found Roboto-Medium

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts

When enabling java Exceptions and Common language runtime exceptions in Exception settings, throws an “Java.Lang.RuntimeException : Font asset not found Roboto-Medium” exception when trying to run the below code snippets (Xamarin.Forms). Even if added Roboto-Medium.ttf file also.

[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL32G.png)
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hro2d.png)

Is there any ways to resolve?

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images.  Have you followed ALL of the steps in the [docs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/embedded-fonts-xamarin-forms/) on using custom fonts?

Comment: Did you set the correct buid action for the .ttf file?